# Error resolving a NSNetService

Tags: iphone, sockets, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

I'm creating a board game to be played via wi-fi, in the iPhone.

When device A invites device B to play(try to resolve the NSNetService published by B), device B can accept or decline.

If B declines, A is notified and everything is fine. But if A try to invite B again later, i get the following error in my ***netService:didNotResolve:*** delegate method.

*NSNetServicesErrorCode = -72003
 NSNetServicesErrorDomain = 10*

The error -72003 means **NSNetServicesActivityInProgress**...How can i proceed to let one player "invite" other player more than once ?

I'm using the AsynchSocket libray, thanks!

Comment: Post some of your code to illustrate what you are currently doing

Comment: When the browser find a new service, i add it to the array and call [service resolveWithTimeout:]. When netServiceDidResolveAddress: is called, i connect my socket to this new service using [self.socket connectToAddress:error:]...When the user touches a row of my tableView, i grab the service from the array and call again [self.socket connectToAddress:error:]...it works now, but i think i have to connect only when the user request...am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i figure that out.

What i'm doing is to resolve the NSNetService as quick as possible in the browserDidFind: delegate method. When a need to connect i call [socket connectToAddress:], passing the NSNetService address, no more errors!

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before [service resolveWithTimeout:] call [service stop]